Form with multiple inputs into fields for PHP processing
I've got a form with multiple sets of data (which are variable) which I'm attempting to pass into PHP and then for each group of fields, have the individual data into PHP variables ready so I can work with them
My form looks like this :
<input type="hidden" name="group[0]form[][familymember]" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="group[0]form[][requestchecked]" value="1">
<textarea name="group[0]form[][requestmessage]" ></textarea>                                                                           

    
<input type="hidden" name="group[1]form[][familymember]" value="30">
<input type="checkbox" name="group[1]form[][requestchecked]" value="1">
<textarea name="group[1]form[][requestmessage]" ></textarea>

    
<input type="hidden" name="group[2]form[][familymember]" value="31">
<input type="checkbox"  name="group[2]form[][requestchecked]" value="1">
<textarea name="group[2]form[][requestmessage]"></textarea>

And my PHP code is as below :
foreach ( $_POST['group'] as $group ) {
    
    foreach ( $group['form'] as $member) {
        $thisfamilymember = $member['familymember'];
        $thisrequestmessage = $member['requestmessage'];
        $thisrequestchecked = $member['requestchecked'];
    }
    
    echo "<br>thisfamilymember = ".$thisfamilymember;
    echo "<br>thisrequestmessage = ".$thisrequestmessage;
    echo "<br>thisrequestchecked = ".$thisrequestchecked;   
}

However rather than getting 9 lines showing the various data thats been entered in the form, all the echo commands come back showing the variables are empty :
thisfamilymember =
thisrequestmessage =
thisrequestchecked =
thisfamilymember =
thisrequestmessage =
thisrequestchecked =
thisfamilymember =
thisrequestmessage =
thisrequestchecked =


var_dump($_POST); to ensure it contains what you think it contains.

And if you post that output here, we should be able to fix your loops.

Use echo '<pre>'; var_dump($_POST); echo '</pre>'; so the formatting is preserved.

i think probrem is how you handling your for each
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
foreach ($_POST['group'] as $group) {
$thisfamilymember = $group['familymember'];
$thisrequestmessage = $group['requestmessage'];
$thisrequestchecked = isset($group['requestchecked']) ? $group['requestchecked'] : 0;
echo "thisfamilymember = " . htmlspecialchars($thisfamilymember);
echo "thisrequestmessage = " . htmlspecialchars($thisrequestmessage);
echo "thisrequestchecked = " . htmlspecialchars($thisrequestchecked);
}
}

"Edit - so I've made the following change to the form and it now works" - Awesome! Please remove the fix from your question; having it in the self-answer is enough.

I've made the following change to the form and it now works
<input type="hidden" name="group[0][form][0][familymember]" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="group[0][form][0][requestchecked]" value="1">
<textarea name="group[0][form][0][requestmessage]" ></textarea>                                                                        

<input type="hidden" name="group[1][form][0][familymember]" value="30">
<input type="checkbox" name="group[1][form][0][requestchecked]" value="1">
<textarea name="group[1][form][0][requestmessage]" ></textarea>

<input type="hidden" name="group[2][form][0][familymember]" value="31">
<input type="checkbox"  name="group[2][form][0][requestchecked]" value="1">
<textarea name="group[2][form][0][requestmessage]"></textarea>


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
